# Make datalist into 3 x 3

Tags: vb.net, datalist

This is my code behind for products page. The prodblem is that my datalist will fill in new items whenever I add a new object in the website. So may I know how to add the codes in so that I can make the datalist into 3x3. 
Thanks.

Code behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim Product As New Product
        Dim DataSet As New DataSet
        Dim pds As New PagedDataSource
        DataSet = Product.GetProduct
        Session("Dataset") = DataSet
        pds.PageSize = 4
        pds.AllowPaging = True
        pds.CurrentPageIndex = 1
        Session("Page") = pds
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            UpdateDatabind()
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub UpdateDatabind()
        Dim DataSet As DataSet = Session("DataSet")
        If DataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            pds.DataSource = DataSet.Tables(0).DefaultView
            Session("Page") = pds
            dlProducts.DataSource = DataSet.Tables(0).DefaultView
            dlProducts.DataBind()
            lblCount.Text = DataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub dlProducts_UpdateCommand(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs) Handles dlProducts.UpdateCommand
        dlProducts.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Public Sub PrevNext_Command(source As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
        Dim pds As PagedDataSource = Session("Page")
        Dim CurrentPage = pds.CurrentPageIndex
        If e.CommandName = "Previous" Then
            If CurrentPage < 1 Or CurrentPage = pds.IsFirstPage Then
                CurrentPage = 1
            Else
                CurrentPage -= 1
            End If
            UpdateDatabind()
        ElseIf e.CommandName = "Next" Then
            If CurrentPage > pds.PageCount Or CurrentPage = pds.IsLastPage Then
                CurrentPage = CurrentPage
            Else
                CurrentPage += 1
            End If
            UpdateDatabind()
        End If
        Response.Redirect("Products.aspx?PageIndex=" & CurrentPage)
    End Sub
```

this is my code for product.vb

```
Public Function GetProduct() As DataSet
        Dim strConn As String
        strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HomeFurnitureConnectionString").ToString
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
        Dim strSql As String
        strSql = "SELECT p.ProdName, p.UnitPrice, pd.Color, pd.PDPic FROM Product p INNER JOIN ProductDetail pd ON p.ProdID = pd.ProdID  " & _
                 "WHERE pd.PdColor = (SELECT min(PdColor) FROM ProductDetail as pd1 WHERE pd1.ProdID = p.ProdID)"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSql, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(ds)
        conn.Close()
        Return ds
    End Function
```

Comment: You have commented sql query to get the product details. If you have fetched product details then in the dataset you will product details like name, code etc. What do you want?

Comment: Oops. I forgot to uncomment it. And I changed the sql query already. So is it still possible to make a 3x3 datalist?

Comment: Its not like 3x3 datalist. A datatable is exactly like your table which you will fetch by query. You can access datatable like dataTable.Row[rowIndex][columnName].

Comment: Is there any examples for it? I tried Dim DataRow As New DataRow
            DataRow = DataSet.Tables("Products").Rows[0]("ProdID") but it gave me an error